# Servo motor always limited in range?

Tags: servo

I am reading up on (servo) motors to start to play around with them. It seems to be that all servo's are limited in range. Most have a 180 degrees range I read.

This would mean that the shaft of a servo never rotates a full cycle.

Is this really the case or I am missing the obvious here?

Comment: Are you only looking at hobby servos for, for instance, RC cars?  There are many types of servo motors and many (most?) can rotate continuously in either direction indefinitely.

Comment: A servomotor is designed to rotate to a specific position depending on the input you feed it. That necessarily means there must be a limited number of possible positions. There are also "continuous-rotation servos", which go at a speed proportional to the input rather than to a position proportional to the input, though.

Comment: Yes definetilly for hobby projectes. I was looking at e.g. Parallax Inc Servo Servo Motor, 140 mA, 4 → 6 V, 27 Ncm (https://nl.rs-online.com/web/p/dc-motors/7813058/). I am trying to figure out what kind of motor I need for a RC boat. It doesn't have to go fast at all. So I read about brushed/brushless DC motors where brushless seems to be the better option since they don't wear/tear as fast. But when I look for brushless motors they go around 300 euro's which is way over budget. So I thought maybe I should go for a servo since they are cheaper. I guess they are brushed too then...

Comment: @bas There are cheap BLDC motors out there! [this one](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/dfrobot/FIT0632/11508206) for instance, came up in a quick search.

Comment: Product usage/purchase selection questions aren't on topic here.  You seem to be confusing "control" motors (as might _aim_ the propeller) with "propulsion" motors which might spin it.  An RC hobby forum would help you find appropriate solutions for both needs on a model boat.

Comment: Unfortunately, "servo" is kind of a overloaded term, meaning that it refers to lots of different things which aren't really the same. What they generally have in common is some ability to accurately control either speed or position or torque somewhat accurately. The kind you are talking about with limited range of motion are servos for controlling the throttle or steering or control surfaces in radio-controlled applications (such as cars and airplanes and boats). But servomotors are used extensively in industrial applications for everything imaginable that requires precise control of a motor.

Comment: These industrial servomotors can rotate continuously and can be controlled to have constant torque or constant speed or to hold a fixed position despite the presence of torque on the shaft. They are used to control motion of CNC beds, and may even be used as spindle motors in machining applications. Just all kinds of stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RC servo’s use a linear Pot for internal feedback are limited in range usually by the rotary magnet.

But if you have a gear reduced motor e.g. 1000:1 with a sin/cos pot, then you can have continuous 360 deg control. But these are vastly more expensive. I used them in the late 70’s with Bourne Pots and Swiss motors for an XY scope auto zero and rotate phase to a reference from an eddy current test signal.

- stepper servos use an external “home” or Trk0  index sensor for a reference like Floppy Disk drive head actuators for continuous control.;

Comment: Not trying to claim I understand half of what you wrote. But vastly more expensive is what I did get. So it doesn't sound like I am looking for a servo

Comment: DIY servo’s can be an optical encoder on the shaft which depend on resolution and quality can be cheap or $$ So the Hobby RC servo’s are cheapest. If you need more range... use rubber gear belt and tiny pulley , 8mm is common, you might need 2mm..